# Restore world transformation exactly after change world transformation

Tags: transform, precision, gdi

The world transformation is internal stored in the dc with double precision. GetWorldTransform and SetWorldTransform works with single precision. So we can lost precision if we use this functions.
An example:

```
mSave = GetWoldTransform(dc);
SetWorldTransform(dc, mytransform);
SetWorldTransform(dc, mSave);
```

After this the world transformation is not exactly the same as before.
I know, I can save/ restore the dc, but this is not the best way because of costs too many time.

How I can exactly save/ restore the current world transformation?

The restore of the saved world transformation must exactly restore the world transformation matrix.